# Specifying limits of a continuous log-transformed x-axis in forestplot R

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am trying to plot data onto a graph with a log-transformed, continuous x-axis. My code is as follows:

(sample data for forestplot)

```
    tabletext <- cbind(c("Analysis","combined","A","B"),
    c("Observational","0.92 [0.87,0.96]","0.94 [0.89,1.01]","0.88 [0.82,0.95]"),
    c("MR","0.95 [0.92,0.98]","0.96 [0.92,1.00]","0.87 [0.78,0.97]")) 
    mean_mr <- c(NA,0.95,0.96,0.84)
    mean_obs <- c(NA,0.92,0.94,0.85)
    lower_mr <- c(NA,0.92,0.92,0.78)
    lower_obs <- c(NA,0.87,0.89,0.82) 
    upper_mr <- c(NA, 0.98,1.00,0.97)
    upper_obs <- c(NA,0.96,1.10,0.94)

    mean <- cbind(mean_obs,mean_mr)
    lower <- cbind(lower_obs,lower_mr)
    upper <- cbind(upper_obs,upper_mr)
```

Generate forest plot:

```
    library(forestplot)

    forestplot(tabletext,mean,lower,upper,is.summary=c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,3)),
       boxsize=0.2,hrzl_lines=gpar(lwd=1,columns=1:4),xlog=1,
       col=fpColors(box=c("black"),line=c("black")),
       txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "",cex=1.1), 
       ticks=gpar(fontfamily="",cex=0.8),xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex = 1.1)))
```

I've tried specifying x-axis limits using xlim, but this has no effect on the plot, and xticks seems to override the xlog parameter. I also notice that even if I remove the xlog parameter, I cannot specify x-axis limits. Is there any way I can specify x-axis limits on a (log-transformed) scale in forestplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which forestplot version do you have? 
I found this note on the [help page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html):

"Note: An important difference from the original forestplot is that the current function interprets xlog as the x-axis being in log-format, i.e. you need to provide the data in the antilog/exp format." . To my understanding, xlog just draws the line at 1 instead of 0.

If i run your example with

```
  forestplot(tabletext,mean,lower,upper,is.summary=c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,3)),
           boxsize=0.2,hrzl_lines=gpar(lwd=1,columns=1:4), xlog=1,
           col=fpColors(box=c("black"),line=c("black")),
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "",cex=1.1), 
                            ticks=gpar(fontfamily="",cex=0.8),xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex = 1.1)),
          xticks = c(0.4, 0.77, 0.9, 1)
          )
```

the output is
[image]

-> the limits are changed, as well as the xticks.

Comment: I'm running forestplot 1.7.2, which I have the documentation for. I think I've simply misunderstood what xlog does! Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like "clip" is used to "Lower and upper limits for clipping confidence intervals to arrows" (according to [the forestplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/forestplot.pdf)).

You can stick this in your code: clip(c(lower limit value, upper limit value)).
For example, in your code I set the lower limit as 0.8 and the upper as 1.2:

```
forestplot(tabletext,mean,lower,upper,is.summary=c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,3)), clip(c(0.8, 1.2))
       boxsize=0.2,hrzl_lines=gpar(lwd=1,columns=1:4),xlog=1,
       col=fpColors(box=c("black"),line=c("black")),
       txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "",cex=1.1), 
       ticks=gpar(fontfamily="",cex=0.8),xlab  = gpar(fontfamily = "", cex = 1.1)))
```

[output plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er2ND.jpg)

Weirdly enough the lower limit won't change, but the upper limit got extended , so the xticks no longer override the xlog parameter. Hope this works!